# How to convert a javascript function to angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I use a plugin that use this block of statements to display menus,Now I use it in angular js.

```js
(function(window) {

 'use strict';

 var support = { animations : Modernizr.cssanimations },
  animEndEventNames = { 'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd', 'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd', 'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd', 'animation' : 'animationend' },
  animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ],
  onEndAnimation = function( el, callback ) {
   var onEndCallbackFn = function( ev ) {
    if( support.animations ) {
     if( ev.target != this ) return;
     this.removeEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
    }
    if( callback && typeof callback === 'function' ) { callback.call(); }
   };
   if( support.animations ) {
    el.addEventListener( animEndEventName, onEndCallbackFn );
   }
   else {
    onEndCallbackFn();
   }
  };

 function extend( a, b ) {
  for( var key in b ) { 
   if( b.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
    a[key] = b[key];
   }
  }
  return a;
 }

 function MLMenu(el, options) {
  this.el = el;
  this.options = extend( {}, this.options );
  extend( this.options, options );
  
  // the menus (<ul>´s)
  this.menus = [].slice.call(this.el.querySelectorAll('.menu__level'));
  // index of current menu
  this.current = 0;

  this._init();
 }

 MLMenu.prototype.options = {
  // show breadcrumbs
  breadcrumbsCtrl : true,
  // initial breadcrumb text
  initialBreadcrumb : 'all',
  // show back button
  backCtrl : true,
  // delay between each menu item sliding animation
  itemsDelayInterval : 60,
  // direction 
  direction : 'r2l',
  // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked
  // onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
  onItemClick : function(ev, itemName) { return false; }
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._init = function() {
  // iterate the existing menus and create an array of menus, more specifically an array of objects where each one holds the info of each menu element and its menu items
  this.menusArr = [];
  var self = this;
  this.menus.forEach(function(menuEl, pos) {
   var menu = {menuEl : menuEl, menuItems : [].slice.call(menuEl.querySelectorAll('.menu__item'))};
   self.menusArr.push(menu);

   // set current menu class
   if( pos === self.current ) {
    classie.add(menuEl, 'menu__level--current');
   }
  });

  // create back button
  if( this.options.backCtrl ) {
   this.backCtrl = document.createElement('button');
   this.backCtrl.className = 'menu__back menu__back--hidden';
   this.backCtrl.setAttribute('aria-label', 'Go back');
   this.backCtrl.innerHTML = '<span class="icon icon--arrow-left"></span>';
   this.el.insertBefore(this.backCtrl, this.el.firstChild);
  }
  
  
  // create breadcrumbs
  if( self.options.breadcrumbsCtrl ) {
   this.breadcrumbsCtrl = document.createElement('nav');
   this.breadcrumbsCtrl.className = 'menu__breadcrumbs';
   this.el.insertBefore(this.breadcrumbsCtrl, this.el.firstChild);
   // add initial breadcrumb
   this._addBreadcrumb(0);
  }

  // event binding
  this._initEvents();
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._initEvents = function() {
  var self = this;

  for(var i = 0, len = this.menusArr.length; i < len; ++i) {
   this.menusArr[i].menuItems.forEach(function(item, pos) {
    item.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(ev) { 
     var submenu = ev.target.getAttribute('data-submenu'),
      itemName = ev.target.innerHTML,
      subMenuEl = self.el.querySelector('ul[data-menu="' + submenu + '"]');

     // check if there's a sub menu for this item
     if( submenu && subMenuEl ) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      // open it
      self._openSubMenu(subMenuEl, pos, itemName);
     }
     else {
      // add class current
      var currentlink = self.el.querySelector('.menu__link--current');
      if( currentlink ) {
       classie.remove(self.el.querySelector('.menu__link--current'), 'menu__link--current');
      }
      classie.add(ev.target, 'menu__link--current');
      
      // callback
      self.options.onItemClick(ev, itemName);
     }
    });
   });
  }
  
  // back navigation
  if( this.options.backCtrl ) {
   this.backCtrl.addEventListener('click', function() {
    self._back();
   });
  }
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._openSubMenu = function(subMenuEl, clickPosition, subMenuName) {
  if( this.isAnimating ) {
   return false;
  }
  this.isAnimating = true;
  
  // save "parent" menu index for back navigation
  this.menusArr[this.menus.indexOf(subMenuEl)].backIdx = this.current;
  // save "parent" menu´s name
  this.menusArr[this.menus.indexOf(subMenuEl)].name = subMenuName;
  // current menu slides out
  this._menuOut(clickPosition);
  // next menu (submenu) slides in
  this._menuIn(subMenuEl, clickPosition);
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._back = function() {
  if( this.isAnimating ) {
   return false;
  }
  this.isAnimating = true;

  // current menu slides out
  this._menuOut();
  // next menu (previous menu) slides in
  var backMenu = this.menusArr[this.menusArr[this.current].backIdx].menuEl;
  this._menuIn(backMenu);

  // remove last breadcrumb
  if( this.options.breadcrumbsCtrl ) {
   this.breadcrumbsCtrl.removeChild(this.breadcrumbsCtrl.lastElementChild);
  }
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._menuOut = function(clickPosition) {
  // the current menu
  var self = this,
   currentMenu = this.menusArr[this.current].menuEl,
   isBackNavigation = typeof clickPosition == 'undefined' ? true : false;

  // slide out current menu items - first, set the delays for the items
  this.menusArr[this.current].menuItems.forEach(function(item, pos) {
   item.style.WebkitAnimationDelay = item.style.animationDelay = isBackNavigation ? parseInt(pos * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms' : parseInt(Math.abs(clickPosition - pos) * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms';
  });
  // animation class
  if( this.options.direction === 'r2l' ) {
   classie.add(currentMenu, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');
  }
  else {
   classie.add(currentMenu, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight'); 
  }
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._menuIn = function(nextMenuEl, clickPosition) {
  var self = this,
   // the current menu
   currentMenu = this.menusArr[this.current].menuEl,
   isBackNavigation = typeof clickPosition == 'undefined' ? true : false,
   // index of the nextMenuEl
   nextMenuIdx = this.menus.indexOf(nextMenuEl),

   nextMenuItems = this.menusArr[nextMenuIdx].menuItems,
   nextMenuItemsTotal = nextMenuItems.length;

  // slide in next menu items - first, set the delays for the items
  nextMenuItems.forEach(function(item, pos) {
   item.style.WebkitAnimationDelay = item.style.animationDelay = isBackNavigation ? parseInt(pos * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms' : parseInt(Math.abs(clickPosition - pos) * self.options.itemsDelayInterval) + 'ms';

   // we need to reset the classes once the last item animates in
   // the "last item" is the farthest from the clicked item
   // let's calculate the index of the farthest item
   var farthestIdx = clickPosition <= nextMenuItemsTotal/2 || isBackNavigation ? nextMenuItemsTotal - 1 : 0;

   if( pos === farthestIdx ) {
    onEndAnimation(item, function() {
     // reset classes
     if( self.options.direction === 'r2l' ) {
      classie.remove(currentMenu, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');
      classie.remove(nextMenuEl, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
     }
     else {
      classie.remove(currentMenu, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-outToLeft' : 'animate-outToRight');
      classie.remove(nextMenuEl, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
     }
     classie.remove(currentMenu, 'menu__level--current');
     classie.add(nextMenuEl, 'menu__level--current');

     //reset current
     self.current = nextMenuIdx;

     // control back button and breadcrumbs navigation elements
     if( !isBackNavigation ) {
      // show back button
      if( self.options.backCtrl ) {
       classie.remove(self.backCtrl, 'menu__back--hidden');
      }
      
      // add breadcrumb
      self._addBreadcrumb(nextMenuIdx);
     }
     else if( self.current === 0 && self.options.backCtrl ) {
      // hide back button
      classie.add(self.backCtrl, 'menu__back--hidden');
     }

     // we can navigate again..
     self.isAnimating = false;
    });
   }
  }); 
  
  // animation class
  if( this.options.direction === 'r2l' ) {
   classie.add(nextMenuEl, !isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
  }
  else {
   classie.add(nextMenuEl, isBackNavigation ? 'animate-inFromRight' : 'animate-inFromLeft');
  }
 };

 MLMenu.prototype._addBreadcrumb = function(idx) {
  if( !this.options.breadcrumbsCtrl ) {
   return false;
  }

  var bc = document.createElement('a');
  bc.innerHTML = idx ? this.menusArr[idx].name : this.options.initialBreadcrumb;
  this.breadcrumbsCtrl.appendChild(bc);

  var self = this;
  bc.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();

   // do nothing if this breadcrumb is the last one in the list of breadcrumbs
   if( !bc.nextSibling || self.isAnimating ) {
    return false;
   }
   self.isAnimating = true;
   
   // current menu slides out
   self._menuOut();
   // next menu slides in
   var nextMenu = self.menusArr[idx].menuEl;
   self._menuIn(nextMenu);

   // remove breadcrumbs that are ahead
   var siblingNode;
   while (siblingNode = bc.nextSibling) {
    self.breadcrumbsCtrl.removeChild(siblingNode);
   }
  });
 };

 window.MLMenu = MLMenu;

})(window);
```

and customized java script :

```js
(function() {
     var menuEl = document.getElementById('ml-menu');
   mlmenu = new MLMenu(menuEl, {
    // breadcrumbsCtrl : true, // show breadcrumbs
    // initialBreadcrumb : 'all', // initial breadcrumb text
    backCtrl : false, // show back button
    // itemsDelayInterval : 60, // delay between each menu item sliding animation
    onItemClick: loadDummyData // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked - onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
   });

   //mobile menu toggle
  var openMenuCtrl = document.querySelector('.action--open'),
   closeMenuCtrl = document.querySelector('.action--close');

  openMenuCtrl.addEventListener('click', openMenu);
  closeMenuCtrl.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);

  function openMenu() {
   classie.add(menuEl, 'menu--open');
  }

  function closeMenu() {
   classie.remove(menuEl, 'menu--open');
  }

  // simulate grid content loading
  var gridWrapper = document.querySelector('.content');

  function loadDummyData(ev, itemName) {
   ev.preventDefault();

   closeMenu();
   gridWrapper.innerHTML = '';
   classie.add(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
   setTimeout(function() {
    classie.remove(gridWrapper, 'content--loading');
    gridWrapper.innerHTML = '<ul class="products">' + dummyData[itemName] + '<ul>';
   }, 700);
  }
 })();
```

I want convert a part of this below customized script to angular js.

```js
mlmenu = new MLMenu(menuEl, {
    // breadcrumbsCtrl : true, // show breadcrumbs
    // initialBreadcrumb : 'all', // initial breadcrumb text
    backCtrl : false, // show back button
    // itemsDelayInterval : 60, // delay between each menu item sliding animation
    onItemClick: loadDummyData // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked - onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
   });
```

I use it as this in angular but it has error .

```js
    $scope.menuEl = document.getElementById('ml-menu');
     var menuEl = document.getElementById('ml-menu'),
     mlmenu = new MLMenu(menuEl, {
                
                 // breadcrumbsCtrl : true, // show breadcrumbs
                 // initialBreadcrumb : 'all', // initial breadcrumb text
                 backCtrl: false, // show back button
                 // itemsDelayInterval : 60, // delay between each menu item sliding animation
                 onItemClick: $scope.loadDummyData // callback: item that doesn´t have a submenu gets clicked - onItemClick([event], [inner HTML of the clicked item])
     });
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your plugin with AngularJS directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

I.e. create directive that uses your plugin and initialize it on marked DOM.

```
angular.module('yourModule')
.directive('mlMenu', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element) {
      var mlmenu = new MLMenu(element,
      ...
    }
  };
});
```

Than in HTML

```
<div data-ml-menu></div>
```

And if you are going to modify scope in plugin listeners do not forget to use `scope.$apply()` wrapper.